# How to send bulk emails with different subjects using Mandrill API?

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

How am I supposed to do to send bulk emails with dynamics subjects?

For example, If I need to send 200 emails at once, I don't want to call the Mandrill send() method 200 times because I suppose it's a very bad practice.

I'd want to call the send() method 1 time, putting my 200 recipients in the `to` attribute (this works well). However, in that case, how to set a different mail subject for each mail sent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use merge tags within your subject to change the subject line for each user.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/28499087-Can-I-use-merge-tags-in-my-subject-line-or-other-headers-

You can provide a default value for your merge tag and/or for each/some users personalised data.

Answer (score -1):

Given the anatomy of an e-mail in Mandril is based upon subject and body (or template) to define a unique entity what you are asking to do isn't possible. A different subject or body constitutes a different e-mail and requires it's own `.send()`.

If the same e-mail (same subject and body/template) was being sent to all receipts then a single `.send()` would work.